# Unable to launch native iOS App from Macbook into iPad2 using Appium and Java

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation

I am struggling from very long time to invoke iOS native app(.app file) from my Macbook into real device iPad2. Please Help!
Here is my POC description:

Task to do: iOS Automation of native .app file using #Appium#Java#SeleniumJarfiles#OnRealIOSDeviceiPAD2#TestNG

Devices used: Macbook (iOS 10.10.1),xCode(6.3),with command line tool installed:->Eclipse Kepler,Appium 1.3.4,iPad2(iOS 8.3),JDK(1.8.25),All required Selenium,Appium_Client jar files.

Here is my setup method to launch native app on iPad2 from macbook(with Appium-node.js)

```
@Test   
public void setUp() throws Exception

{

    // set up appium
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "seerut");  
     capabilities.setCapability("PlatformName", "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability("PlatformVersion", "8.1");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.wooqer.wooqer");
     capabilities.setCapability("udid","df5f3518932eb98b90b452c904dccfd2cd510dac");
     capabilities.setCapability("bundleid", "com.wooqer.wooqer");

     File app = new File("/Users/wooqer/Desktop/Anil/Payload/Wooqer.app");
     capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

     driver = new IOSDriver( new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     System.out.println("App launched");    
 }
```

Comment: Unable to install [/Users/wooqer/Desktop/Anil/Payload/Wooqer.app] to device with id [df5f3518932eb98b90b452c904dccfd2cd510dac]. Error [Error: Command failed: Assertion failed: (AMDeviceStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.afc"), &afcFd, NULL) == 0), function handle_device, file fruitstrap.c, line 523.
]at/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:147:10 at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:662:7) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)at Process.ChildProcess. handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

Answer (score 0):

Appium seems to have a known problem with installing an app to a physical device for the first time. Try installing the app to the device manually first and then running your program. Also looking at your code I notice that you are trying to configure appium with the capabilities for both a physical device and simulator below are the capabilities required for each.

iOS Physical device: deviceName, platformVersion, udid, bundleid, app. //Note that for physical device you should be giving an absolute path to the .ipa

iOS Simulator: deviceName, platformVersion, app. //For this an absolute path to the .app will do.

Also make sure that the app you are building (if you are building it) is created for the correct architecture. iOS sim can only run x86 apps, and physical device ArmV7 apps.